# Sequelizejs: How to eager load a 'structured' assosiation?

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, eager-loading, populate

I have a database scheme like this:
[Scheme image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xPL.png)

The only relation I made is this:

```
db.routines.hasMany(db.elements, {constraints: false});
```

I'm trying to find a routine, with all elements populated/eager-loaded, but I don't know how to achieve this, I'm trying this:

```
db.routines.findAll({
    include: [{ all: true }]
}).then(routines => {
    res.send(routines)
})
```

or

```
db.routines.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: db.elements
    }]
}).then(routines => {
    res.send(routines)
})
```

Both result in the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "f45273da-eb13-45a2-852c-81b8eee14eb8",
        "element_1": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
        "element_2": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
        "element_3": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
        "element_4": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
        "element_5": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
        "diff1": null,
        "diff2": null,
        "created_at": "2017-12-12T21:04:15.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-12T21:04:15.000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "elements": []
    }
]
```

But what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "f45273da-eb13-45a2-852c-81b8eee14eb8",
        "element_1": {
            "id": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
            "name_en": "Backflip",
            "name_nl": "Salto",
            .....
        },
        "element_2": {
            "id": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
            "name_en": "Backflip",
            "name_nl": "Salto",
            .....
        },
        "element_3": {
            "id": "8d609633-1554-41cd-a47e-244508ebe77c",
            "name_en": "Backflip",
            "name_nl": "Salto",
            .....
        },
        .....
    }
]
```

How do I populate this? The only examples I find are retrieving an object of elements, which is not what I want, since they have to have a specific index.